# How to define accepting states in a finite automation?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

I can build a finite automation from a dataset and would be glad to expand that to a deterministic finite automation (DFA). A DFA requires accepting states. How one can identify them, or how these can be defined?

Is there any proper definition for accepting states? What is the difference of accepting states from all other states?

Comment: What is your automaton supposed to do?

Comment: An accepting state is defined as the states that your machine will accept its input on if it has fully consumed the input and has ended execution in that state. As long as you have some way of expressing states with that property (typically with a boolean or enum on the state, or a list of accepting states on the machine), then you're good.

Answer (score 1):

After processing a string in your language as input, your deterministic finite automaton should end processing in an accepting state. On the other hand, after processing a string not in your language as input, your deterministic finite automaton should not end processing in an accepting state. You should choose your accepting states such that these two conditions hold for all the strings in your language.